# External link not working in Spring Unit Testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my code for token I used external link . External link open in browser but not working in unit testing code. Any suggestion.

My code

```
           private String getHRCToken() throws Exception {
            
            String token="";
            
            
            MultiValueMap<String, String> variables = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            variables.add("email", HRC_LOGIN_EMAIL);
            variables.add("password", HRC_LOGIN_PASSWORD);
            
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
            requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(variables ,
                    requestHeaders);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(BASE_URL, HttpMethod.POST,
                    requestEntity, String.class);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        }

        @Test
            public void updateData() throws Exception {
                String URI = "/reviewData/leads/update";
                String token = getHRCToken();
                MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put(URI)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .header("Authorization", token).param("status", "New")
                        .param("lead_id", "1")
                        ).andReturn();
                //Checking if our service has issues
                assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
                String response = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
                int i = response.indexOf("{");
                response = response.substring(i);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.trim());
                JSONObject responseObject = json;
                String message = responseObject.getString("message");
                //Checking if process as exepected
                assertTrue(message.equalsIgnoreCase("success"));
            }
```

Error

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 null
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:708)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:539)

Comment: HTTP Status 415 means Unsupported Media Type. You most likely did not set a correct Content-Type or Accept header in your request (RestTemplate).

Comment: Please show us your code and elaborate what exactly means "not working" to understand your question in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set content type on the header instance, like

headerObj.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)